# udev: waiting for uevents to be processed on my Gentoo

Tags: linux, boot, gentoo, udev

During the startup I see machine executing this thing for about 30 seconds:

```
udev: waiting for uevents to be processed
```

Then I get a quick message which says something like:

```
devfs: timeout (50 seconds)
```

I can't see the whole thing because after that system starts up very fast including Xfce.

What logs and configs do I need to provide for further investigation?

$uname -a

```
Linux genta 3.6.6-gentoo #1 SMP Sun Nov 11 11:02:23 NOVT 2012 i686 Genuine Intel(R) CPU T2300 @ 1.66GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Thank you!

**UPD: rc-status**

```
genta / # rc-status sysinit
Runlevel: sysinit
 dmesg                                                             [  started  ]
 udev                                                              [  started  ]
 devfs                                                             [  started  ]
genta / # rc-status boot
Runlevel: boot
 hwclock                                                           [  started  ]
 modules                                                           [  started  ]
 fsck                                                              [  started  ]
 root                                                              [  started  ]
 mtab                                                              [  started  ]
 localmount                                                        [  started  ]
 sysctl                                                            [  started  ]
 bootmisc                                                          [  started  ]
 hostname                                                          [  started  ]
 termencoding                                                      [  started  ]
 keymaps                                                           [  started  ]
 net.lo                                                            [  started  ]
 swap                                                              [  started  ]
 urandom                                                           [  started  ]
 procfs                                                            [  started  ]
```

**UPD 2: kernel-config**

```
genta / # cat /etc/kernels/kernel-config-x86_64-3.6.6-gentoo | grep 'DEVTMPFS\|UEVENT'
CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER_PATH="/usr/bin/udevadm"
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been finally able to fix this thing.

The thing is - I have two partitions: `/boot` and `/`, but I was using **initramfs** to start the system. At that time I wasn't quite sure if I need it or not, but now after gaining some experience (building LFS ;)) I understood that I just don't need it, and removed the `initrd` line from my `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file

Answer (score 3):

For further investigation you can configure `udev` to report more verbose messages by editing  `/etc/udev/udev.conf` to the following and rebooting:

```
udev_log="err"
```

You can set it back to `"info"` after finished debugging. Messages from `udev` should now be reported to the `var/log/messages` file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's the [messages output](http://stan-gentoo.blogspot.com)

Comment: @stan31337 Please add any additional information to your question rather than editing answers

Comment: @Paul sorry, my bad...

Comment: Gentoo: /var/log/messages: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your kernel, make sure the following configuration options are set in your Drivers -> Generic section:

```
CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER_PATH="/usr/bin/udevadm"
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y
```

These are not the defaults.

Also run these to add to your init:

```
rc-update add sysfs sysinit
rc-update add udev-mount sysinit
```

Are you using an initramrs? Do you have /usr on a separate partition?

Comment: I've changed **CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER_PATH** and recompiled the kernel. Other two options were enabled.

Comment: And remove devfs from all of your runlevels. You don't need it.

Comment: After removing devfs from all runlevels the system was starting few seconds slower, and after that I could not launch chromium. **/etc/init.d/devfs start** helped, so I've returned devfs back to sysinit where it was.

Comment: ok. I assume you are booting your new kernel?

Comment: Can you update with the status of `rc-status sysinit` and `rc-status boot`?

Comment: Updated. As for the kernel - I've started new one before deleting devfs from runlevels and it worked fine.

Comment: I've tried to removing unused stuff from kernel, it didn't help much...

Comment: I updated my answer. Its are to tell without being able to take a look at it.

Comment: I've just done what you suggested in update and restarted - no change  :(
I'm using **initramfs**, **/usr** is on the same partition as **/** (SSD disk), **/home** is mounted to HDD

Comment: Are you sure you're using the kernel that you just built with the new settings?

Comment: **UPD2** in question shows output of my current config with **UEVENT** and **DEVTMPFS** options